# MongoLab (Mongodb) is slow when query old data

Tags: mongodb, mlab

We are using MongoLabs and when I query my old data it never returns me results and my web-app simply timeout. I can guess that old data is in the disk and searching through disk is slow. But really does mongodb store all the new data in RAM ? Most of recent data works fine.

What is the real cause for this ? Is there any solutions for make it even. I have 32,401,864 documents in my database and have already created enough indexes based on queries and have TTL set to 100 days.

Number of documents I have is super high for mongodb ?

Comment: If you haven't already, feel free to contact support@mongolab.com with details on your issue. We'll be happy to investigate.

Answer (score 0):

If you haven't attempted this already, try turning on the profiler, in the *tools* tab and the *commands* subtab. Then select the *profile (log slow)* command. Also, try examining the *system.profile* collection, since the profiler deposits all profile data into a collection called *system.profile*. After running your application for a bit, go into the *system.profile* collection and take a looksee. Just a side note, you don'w ant to leave the profiler on if you're not using it. There is a bit of overhead if you don't turn it off. select *profile turn off* command from the menu and then run the command

Comment: appreciate your response. Sure I did try that but I failed to do profiling and got the following error, {
    "serverUsed": "terminus1.mongolab.com:48410",
    "ok": 0,
    "errmsg": "profile currently not supported via mongos"
}